# Low Voltage; Remote Only Ceiling Fan/Light

Tags: electrical, wiring

Pulled power for remote-only ceiling fan/light from box where the receptacle is pigtailed from source and daisy-chained receptacles in the same room.

Fan and light (which worked for several years) stopped. We received a warranty remote module and after some swapping with one of the other five working fans, it began working.

Now after  several months it stopped again. No part swapping helped this time. I decided to check the circuit.

The voltage at that receptacle box hot-neutral is 120v. Voltage across hot-neutral at ceiling fan box 77v. What happened?

Comment: What's above the ceiling the fan is hung from?  Is it an attic where possible something chewed at the cable?

Comment: No attic, 5-1/2” of insulation and then container roof.

Answer (score 1):

Loose connection, or possibly broken wire. Could well be the "77V" is phantom voltage and what you really have is no connection on one of the wires. Check the connections.

Comment: Will undo and redo connections in receptacle box and report back.

Comment: It was a loose neutral under the wire nut in the receptacle box.